# Approximate $\log_{10}$ values without a calculator

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponentiation, approximation, integers

I've got this problem:

> $1,000,000^{{1,000,000}^{1,000,000}} < n^{n^{n^n}}$
>
> What is the first positive integer value of n for which this inequality holds?

I managed to reduce it to this:

> $6+\log_{10}(6) < n\log_{10}(n)$

by using $\log_{10}$ three times (and discarding some of the insignificant values – I can explain why these are insignificant at the end).

The only problem is I don't know how to approximate this (using an upper bound on the left and lower on the right as an upper bound for n, and then the reverse for a lower bound of n) accurately enough.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Also, if anyone has another way of doing this problem without the method I used, avoiding my issue altogether, that would be helpful.

Comment: 6+log(6) is less than 7, so we know n <= 10. Can just test values after

Comment: If you want to completely avoid calculators, you can play tricks like this: $7^6$ and $7^7$ both have $6$ digits, so $6\log_{10} 7$ and $7\log_{10} 7$ are both between $6$ and $7$, and so $\log_{10}7$ is between $\frac67$ and $1$. (The fact that $2^{10}$ is just larger than $10^3$ is a good way to remember that $\log_{10}2$ is just larger than $0.3$.)

Comment: Just for info, you could use other notations, for instance $n\uparrow\uparrow 4>10^6\uparrow\uparrow 3$ is easier to read.

Comment: @kyary, I know that the LHS is less than 7, but the testing values on the RHS is the difficult part, the thing I'm actually trying to find out because I can't work out log10(9), log10(8), etc.

Comment: @GregMartin How would you work out that both $7^6$ and $7^7$ both have 6 digits? Also I think you mean between 5 and 6 => $\log_{10}(7)$ is between $5/6$ and $1$.

Comment: @zwim Thanks, I'll use this in future.

Comment: @icantcode Suppose we wanted to show that 8log8 > log6 + 6. Then you could raise both sides to the 10th power and manually compute both sides by hand. Admittedly, it's ugly but it's doable since the highest number of digits you could be working with is 10 digits

Comment: @kyary I'm sure there's a much simpler solution though

Comment: Why should one think there's a simpler solution? Squaring $8$ three times in a row is about as simple as math gets....

Comment: You're right actually, sorry. When I tried that in my head I made an error, so I thought that was much harder than it was. But in the end that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with limited hand multiplications/additions. Starting from your condition that $6+\log_{10} 6< n\log_{10} n$, notice that
$$
10<6^2<100
\rightarrow 1< 2\log_{10} 6 < 2
\rightarrow 1/2 < \log_{10} 6 < 1
\longrightarrow \fbox{$6.5 < 6+\log_{10} 6 < 7$}.
$$
Also, $6^6=46,656$ (by hand!) therefore
$$
10^4<6^6<10^5
\rightarrow 4 < 6\log_{10} 6 < 5
$$
therefore $n=6$ is too small. On the other hand
$$
\text{with } n=10\quad 10\log_{10} 10 = 10 > 7
$$
therefore $n=10$ is large enough. Between 6 (too small) and 10 (large enough), try 8 :
\begin{align}
& 8^8 = (2^3)^8=2^{24}=(2^{10})^2\times 2^4 > 1000^2\times 16\\
\longrightarrow\quad 
&
8\log_{10} 8 > 2\log_{10} 1000 + \log_{10} 16 > 6+1=7
\end{align}
therefore 8 is also enough. The only remaining possibility is 7:
\begin{align}
& 7^2=49<50 
\rightarrow
7^6<50^3=125,000
\rightarrow
7^7<7\times 125,000=875,000 < 10^6\\
\longrightarrow\quad &
7\log_{10} 7 < 6 
\end{align}
and thus $n=7$ is not enough. The answer is 8.

PS. Using Knuth's up-arrow notation, you get $7\uparrow\uparrow4<(10^6)\uparrow\uparrow3<8\uparrow\uparrow4$.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: $ 8 \log 8 > 6 + \log 6 > 7 \log 7 $.

Because your bounds are extremely weak, you have a lot of flexibility with manipulating the terms. We don't need to manually compute the exact values, but can just approximate them with nice enough values.

Second inequality:  WTS $ 6 \times 10 ^ 6 > 7^ 7$.
This is true because $ 60 \times 10^5 > 7^2 \times 7^5 = 7^7$.

First inequality: Try this on your own, using the same idea as above.

> WTS $  8^8 > 6 \times 10 ^ 6 $
>  This is true because $ 2^2 > 3 $ and $ 2^7 > 5^3 $, so $2^{24} > 2^7 \times 3 \times 5^6 $

Answer (score 0):

Here is your starting point in working out a table of logs by hand.
$2^{10} = 1024\\
10\log 2 \approx 3\\
\log 2 \approx 0.3$

0.301 is a better estimate, but this is close enough.

From this we get:
$\log 4 \approx 0.6\\
\log 8 \approx 0.9\\
\log 5 = 1 - \log 2 \approx 0.7$

We see:
$8\log 8 \approx 7.2$

To build out some more values we use a little trickery:

$\log 81  = 4\log 3 > 1.8\\
\log 3 \approx 0.45$

This is not so bad an approximation,  it is closer to $0.48$

$\log 6 > 0.75$

$8\log 8 > 6.75$

Comment: $\log_{10}(8)$ is about 0.9 This makes $8\log_{10}(8)$ equal to about 7.2, which is greater than $6 + \log_{10}(6)$

Comment: brain fatigue.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer the question, but without using the triple logarithm section. I log'd it only twice.

https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=29b0e937-b320-4ea3-a427-dfd57f763f43&fn=May+5%2C+Doc+2.pdf&ct=1620251369013&tl=share-document&rf=link

If anyone still knows a way of approximating those logs though, please could you share.